# how to make my timer not reset when browser is refreshed and closed?

Tags: javascript, php, timer

i am making a quiz timer, which contains timer with minute and seconds, my problem here is when i press refresh the timer restarts to its original time. How can i make the timer not reset when i click refresh button or when i close the browser ?. im a little confuse on getting the time when started + (5minutes, sample time for the quiz) then store to database then echo it make it timer

```
<font size="6">
<div style="font-weight: bold" id="quiz-time-left"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var max_time = <?php echo $rows['q_time'] ?>*60;
var c_seconds  = 0;
var total_seconds =max_time;
max_time = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML='Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds';
function init(){
document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML='Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds';
setTimeout("CheckTime()",999);
}
function CheckTime(){
document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML='Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds' ;
if(total_seconds <=0){
setTimeout('document.getElementById("quiz").submit()',1);

    } else
    {
total_seconds = total_seconds -1;
max_time = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
setTimeout("CheckTime()",999);
}

}
init();
</script>
</font>
```

Comment: you can use cookies or send the current timer with get or post on the refresh button. On closing the browser i dont think you can somehow save the time

Comment: yes i found an another topic regarding to refresh and the solution is the document.cookie function, but i need it to work on both refreshing the browser and closing the browser

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to achieve, you can store the starting point of your timer in either a `cookie`, or the browser's `localStorage`.

```
if (window.localStorage["start_time"]){
// continue from start time.
//reset your timer to the time passed since start_time
}else{
//first time load. reset your timer to 0. 

}
```

note that window.localStorage won't work with older browsers and that you might have to do something similar with cookies.

Comment: i am new to window.localStorage, can you explain how can i use them? thank you

Answer (score -1):

My opinions are

1. Store the start time in a database (mysql for example).
2. Or store the start time in the user session on reload or refresh.  Just pull the time out of the session and continue counting.
3. Use a cookie. but I recommend mysql or session, cookie can simply get manipulated.

Comment: cant understand you hehe